# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''

Tags: python, django, web

I would like to ask for a little help regarding a code since when I start it tells me this following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zTpF.png)

Here are the views and code

```
def add(request):

    cart = get_or_create_cart(request)
    producto = Producto.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('product_id'))

    cart.productos.add(producto)

    return render(request, 'carts/add.html', {
        'producto': producto
    })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ulOe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6EQB.png)

Comment: Please add the code to the question, instead of images

Comment: Looks like `producto.id` is an empty string. Look at the generated HTML for your form to verify that's the problem, then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying product_id in the add views as post data but by default django views handles GET request. So, either change views to include product_id as argument and this function will works or change function to handle post request.

Using GET method

```
def add(request, product_id):
    cart = get_or_create_cart(request)
    producto = Producto.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    cart.productos.add(producto)
    return render(request, 'carts/add.html', {
        'producto': producto
    })
```

and your url patterns look like following

```
path('<int:product_id>/', add, name='add')
```

Using POST request

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        cart = get_or_create_cart(request)
        producto = Producto.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('product_id'))
        cart.productos.add(producto)
        return render(request, 'carts/add.html', {
            'producto': producto
        })
    else:
         # something you would like (GET method)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `primary_key=True` to `cart_id` column.
Since you have not added it django added a pk field `id` which is what it's expecting when you query.

After the change make the template code to use `cart_id` instead of `id`

Comment: I implemented what you have told me but keep telling me a mistake about ''int'' and ' '

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?